# Visual Studio Add-in no longer allows me to debug it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

My visual studio addin project will not longer build and run in the debugger. I get the following error message when I try to run it:

```
A project with an Output Type of CLass Library cannot be stared directly.
```

It was working about 5 months ago just fine but I opened it and and ran it for the first time since then and get this message. It used to startup another instance of Visual Studio with the addin installed via a proxy addin file.

How do I configure the project or solution to make it behave this way again? Do I need to manually tweak the project of solution file?

Comment: Do you have another project in the solution that is a Class Library? Then you should set  your addin project as startup Project(right click on it).

Comment: There are two other projects but the addin project is set as the startup project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Some how Visual studio lost the  `Start External Program` and the `Command line arguments` setting values.

Start External Program needs to be set to:

```
[Visual Studio path]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

And the Command line argument should be:

```
/resetaddin [Name of addin].connect
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Visual Studio 2012**

In **Visual Studio 2012**, the settings for a new package project are somewhat different.

Start External Program needs to be set to:

`[Visual Studio path]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

And the Command line argument should be:

`/rootsuffix Exp`